# Points in hosted Feature Layer causing rendering issues in ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: javascript, point, rendering, feature-service, group-layer

I have Feature Service in my ArcGIS Online account that is made up of a number of feature layers. The feature service was created by publishing a file geodatabase. I am adding the Feature Service as a `new GroupLayer()` and passing a `new PortalItem()` to the constructor.

This adds all the feature layers to the map and I can see them in the LayerList. Only features with polyline geometry render properly though. Layers with point geometry cause the [GroupLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GroupLayer.html) to stop rendering (all items in group layer stay at same position on screen even while map is panned/zoomed). It also continuously throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundVAO' of null`

If I toggle the visibility to `false` for all of the point layers and leave only the polyline layers then the map behaves exactly as expected.

What is even more bizarre is if I change the visualization properties of the point layers in ArcGIS Online to display as a heatmap instead of points then the rendering issue goes away.

Is there a way to symbolize the point layers as points in the group layer and still have everything render properly? I have a feeling this is a bug in the Javascript API. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the similar issue with setting option `cacheLayers` to `false`. Request for images for Point layer doesn't perform after first creation, setting  `cacheLayers` to `false` solved this.

```
new L.esri.featureLayer({
    ...,
    cacheLayers: false
});
```

But probably there are side effects in this case.